# Permanently change MAC address?

Tags: networking, mac

I have to change the MAC address of my WiFi card. What's the best approach?

The reason for this is, that I have to use port forwarding on my router, but it has such kind of software which is undesirable, that it only allows port forwarding for connected devices. And it is incapable of recognizing my raspberry PI. So I used a different PC, set up port forwarding rules, and now want to give the Pi the MAC address of said PC.

I have tried this, but it doesn't survive a reboot:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down hw ether ab:ea:5a:a3:bc:01
```

Comment: Depends on your network manager (netplan, NetworkManager, systemd-networkd, ifupdown, ...)

Comment: It can't be "permanently" changed, but you can configure the OS to change it on each boot.  This is an OS and version dependent issue, and (as mentioned above) there are still multiple ways to configure it.

Comment: It's on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To permanently change the MAC address of your WiFi card, you need to modify the system's network configuration files. The specific method varies depending on the operating system you are using, but here are some general steps:

Determine the interface name: Run **ifconfig** to see a list of all network interfaces on your system. Identify the name of the interface you want to modify (e.g. **wlan0**).

Modify network configuration files: The location and name of the network configuration files can vary depending on your operating system and distribution. In most cases, you can find the network configuration files in the **/etc/network** directory. Open the configuration file for the interface you want to modify (e.g. **/etc/network/interfaces**), and add a line to set the MAC address:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
hwaddress ether ab:ea:5a:a3:bc:01
```

Replace **wlan0** and **ab:ea:5a:a3:bc:01** with the appropriate values for your system.

Restart the network interface: Run ifdown **wlan0** followed by **ifup wlan0** to restart the interface and apply the new MAC address.

Test the new MAC address: Run **ifconfig** and look for the interface you modified. The MAC address should be the one you set in the configuration file.

Note that changing the MAC address of your network interface may be a violation of your network provider's terms of service or local laws. Use this information responsibly and only for legal purposes.

Comment: This does work just fine.